# Can MySQL Workbench sync a model diagram with more than one database?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I'd like to use the `Database->Synchronize Model` feature in MySQL Workbench to modify both my production database and a test database (used for automatic phpunit testing of a yii webapp). In the past I've copied the MWB EER model within MySQL Workbench, modified links to the database, and then synced. Before discovering `Synchronize Model` I used to use `Forward Engineer`, search/replace on database name, then run the SQL.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Under the Model tab for a MWB EER diagram you can right click the name of your database in the tab under the window "Physical Schemata" and then just change the database table name before doing `Database->Synchronize Model` to get it to offer a checkbox in the wizard for the new database you'd like to sync to. Don't forget to change the database name back when you're done, though.

Comment: this is a really nice workaround, you should post it as an answer to your own question and then flag it as correct, so that this thread could make more sense. thank you very much!

Comment: thanks @holographix. wasn't sure of proper SO etiquette. done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Model tab for a MWB EER diagram you can right click the name of your database in the tab under the window "Physical Schemata" and then just change the database table name before doing Database->Synchronize Model. That will force it to offer a checkbox in the wizard for the new database you'd like to sync to. Don't forget to change the database name back when you're done, though.